# Learning bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to learn bash scripting on Linux.

Can anyone provide good links for starting bash scripts?

Comment: This pretty much depends on your aim and your favorite way of learning. Why do you want to learn bash? I would recommend simply reading `man bash`, which will lead you through all aspects of bash. Others prefer learning by example, which might give you an easier start, but usually leaves you with only the most basic stuff. (Which might be enough in your case.)

Answer (score 2):

["The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php)" is a fairly comprehensive (freely available) book and may be of help to you.